# paint-order attribute ignored on Chrome

Tags: css

I am attempting to style some text, with white text and a black stroke. I want it to have a thick stroke while still having the text be visible.

For this, I used the following CSS:

```
element {
    -webkit-text-stroke: 6px black;
    color: white;
    paint-order: stroke;
}
```

However, `paint-order` does not function properly on Chrome browsers. Here is a demonstration, Firefox on the left and Chrome on the right. You can see on the right that Chrome is not honoring the `paint-order` attribute, [despite supposedly being compatible since version 35](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/paint-order).

[image]

[The CodeSandbox I made to demonstrate.](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-resonance-nrd0b)

Is there some additional attribute needed for this to work on all browsers? My Chrome version is `80.0.3987.132` and Firefox is `74.0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome only supports `paint-order` on SVG text. There is no support for HTML text, although it could be supported in the future since it's supported in Firefox and Safari. In the meantime you can use `text-shadow` as a fallback for Chrome and older browsers.

Related ticket: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=815111

Comment: `paint-order` affect `path` as well.

Answer (score -1):

**edit** to anyone falling here , `text-shadow` is still the fallback to use   for HTML/CSS and **IE11**, but FF,Chrome and edge will apply it **to your SVG**.

[`-webkit-text-stroke`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke), is non-standard and off  standards track, where **IE11 also fails** .

---

*original answer*

Does your browser supports `paint-order` ?

check it here : https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_paint-order

---

you can use many text-shadow to get the blur effect finally looking alike a stroke effect as a possible alternative:

demo of the idea that's worth what it is:

```css
h1, h2 {
color:white;
text-shadow: 0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black,0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black,0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black,0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black;
letter-spacing:4px;
}

/* dummy demo */
h2 {
text-shadow: 
   0 0 2px blue,0 0 2px blue,0 0 2px blue,0 0 2px blue,0 0 2px blue,
   0 0 4px white,0 0 4px white,0 0 4px white,0 0 4px white,0 0 4px white, 0 0 4px white,0 0 4px white,0 0 4px white,0 0 4px white,0 0 4px white,0 0 4px white,0 0 4px white,0 0 4px white,0 0 4px white,0 0 4px white, 0 0 4px white,0 0 4px white,0 0 4px white,0 0 4px white,0 0 4px white,0 0 4px white,0 0 4px white,0 0 4px white,0 0 4px white,0 0 4px white, 0 0 4px white,0 0 4px white,0 0 4px white,0 0 4px white,0 0 4px white,
   0 0 6px crimson,0 0 6px crimson,0 0 6px crimson,0 0 6px crimson,0 0 6px crimson,0 0 6px crimson,0 0 6px crimson,0 0 6px crimson,0 0 6px crimson,0 0 6px crimson,0 0 6px crimson,0 0 6px crimson,0 0 6px crimson,0 0 6px crimson,0 0 6px crimson,0 0 6px crimson,0 0 6px crimson,0 0 6px crimson,0 0 6px crimson,0 0 6px crimson;
   }
```

```html
<h1>Hello The World</h1>
<h2>Hello The World</h2>
```

---

If you want to implement this average `text-shadow` stroking only where `paint-order` is not implemented, `@supports` could be usefull https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports  /  https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-featurequeries

Comment: `paint-order` is listed as supported on Google Chrome as of version 35, but on my computer with version 80 it is being ignored.